# How to get a specific Cell Address in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to input a specific cell such as cell row 1 column 1 (A1). Here's what I have tried doing but it seems to crash right now.

```
System.String b = oSheetCells.Address[5, 5];
MessageBox.Show(b);
```

I was hoping "b" would return "F5" in this case. `oSheetCells` is a range object. If I did a command for `oSheetCells[1,1].Value`, I'd retrieve the value of cell A1.

Comment: what is returning now ?

Comment: It crashed but I just realized that the variable I used may be incorrect.

Comment: Could you give more context to what you're doing? What is `oSheetCells`? What error are you getting?

Comment: I found the issue guys sorry! oSheetCells was never initialized until later in my code, I assumed it to be different. By using osheet (myworksheet).cells[row,col].address, it seemed to work fine! I just got to circumvent the 2 dots now. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Which library are you using? Could you pkease give more info about it? I used to use DevExpress’s Spreadsheet utils, but it’s not free to use. I guess you’re using the Microsoft Office lib

Answer (score 0):

If it crashes, with the information you provided, the most logical thing is that oSheetCells is not initialized.

Be more careful the next time ;)